# Issue with Threads and auto ViewPager - Android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm breaking my head for the past few days to fix this simple problem.. would be great if someone could give me a hint to solve this.. Here is the scenario,

I've a viewPager in my app which shows 10 different images (say a1.png, b1.png, c1.png, d1.png etc.,) I made use of Threads to do a slideshow of images automatically.. When the user taps on the image - I have to show a2.png. and again if the user taps on the same image I've to show a3.png and so on. After tapping if the user leaves it for a while, the thread will run and shows a3.png,b3.png,c3.png automatically. I'm setting zoom out/in animation when the user taps on the image.

My problem is when the user taps on a1.png it should show a2.png, but it is showing b2.png. here is the code,

```
     ... some code ...
    int currentPage = 0; 
    pageSwitcher(10);  //Switch Pages for every 10 seconds

     ... some code ...

    public void pageSwitcher(int seconds) {
    timer = new Timer(); // At this line a new Thread will be created
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RemindTask(), 0, seconds * 1000); // delay                                                                        // in milliseconds
}

class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
    public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                if (currentPage > 10) { 
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage=0);

                } else {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {

           //Modify the adapter with different set of array and set it to ViewPager

           ... some code ...

           viewPager.setAdapter(adapter); 

           viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage);
       viewPager.startAnimation(anim);
    }

    // I'm cancelling the current running timer when the animation starts and call PageSwitcher function when the animation ends as below,

            anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.scale);
    anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            timer.cancel();
        }
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
             pageSwitcher(10);
        }
    });
```

As mentioned above, the problem is when the user taps on the image (say c3.png) it should show c4.png and the thread should run.. but it is showing d4.png and so on.

Please do let me know if I'm not clear anywhere.. Any pointers would be quite helpful.

Comment: there is no pause for timer you need to cancel and start again.http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: @Raghunandan yes I'm doing timer.cancel() when the animation starts and creating a new timer only. pls check the above code.